# Как вынести useCase в отдельный метод?

Tags: android, kotlin, flow

Не могу показать реальный код (NDA).
Но не могли бы вы мне помочь в измененном примере ?

Мне очень нужно:

1. убрать "GetTextUseCase" из "combine"
2. вызывать formatText без text, formatText(age)
3. СУТЬ ПРОБЛЕМЫ !!!  Получить текст из GetTextUseCase в private fun formatText()

Какие есть способы решения этой проблемы ?

```
Class ClientViewModel(
    private val getText: GetTextUseCase,     // invoke Flow()
    private val getUser: GetUserUseCase,     // invoke Flow()
    private val getAge: GetAgeUseCase,       // invoke Flow()
): ViewModel() {

    val state = combine(
        getText(),
        getUser(),
        getAge(),
    ) { text, user, age ->
           ...some code...
           ...some code...
           ...some code...
           
           NewClient(
               text = formatText(age, text),
               user = user,
               age = age,
           )
      }
      .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, NewClient.DEFAULT)


    private fun formatText(
        age: Int,
        text: String,
    ): String {
        return if (age > 18) {
            "Adult"
        } else {
            "Under 18"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: если я правильно понял, то проблема в том, что `GetTextUseCase` тригерится чаще чем остальные флоу, а вам это не надо. надо получить его актуальыне данные, только при тригере 2 остальных. если это так, то можно сделать `formatText` как `suspend` метод, а внутри него `val text = getText().firstOrNull()`

Comment: Да да ! Именно так !
Спасибо большое Wlad ! 
Получилось !!!